# Intellij - If I run code . in command line to start vscode, how can I do the same in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, command-line

If I run code . in command line to start vscode, how can I do the same in Intellij?

[image]

Comment: already read this article https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/opening-files-from-command-line.html#8d997325 ?

Comment: Are you saying you want to start VSCode from IntelliJ? Are you saying you want to start Intellij by entering `code .`? Do you want a java program that runs `code .`?

Comment: Hi @matt, I mean what command to start Intellij? like using "code ." for vscode.

Comment: How did you install intellij? For me, I run "idea.sh" that comes with intellij.

Comment: Please see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011901879-How-to-start-IDE-from-the-command-line